# Google CSE Site Restricted API returns request throttle quota despite documentation saying no quota

Tags: python, google-api, google-custom-search, google-api-python-client

I'm using they Google Python API Library to call the CSE Site Restrict search. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/site_restricted_api), "this API is similar to the Custom Search JSON API except this version has no daily query limit."

However, after 100 searches I receive a 403 response from the Google API saying "Request throttled due to daily limit being reached." This doesn't seem to make sense, any idea if I'm doing something wrong? Code included below for how I'm calling the siterestrict function.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

CSE_ID = "CSE_ID"
API_KEY = "API_KEY"

service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=API_KEY)

def run_google_search(service, query, **kwargs):
    try:
        res = service.cse().siterestrict().list(q=query, cx=CSE_ID, **kwargs).execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return []
    return res['items']

run_google_search(service, "Test search")
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have billing set up for your API key? If not, then you'll be limited to the 100 free queries per day on either Custom Search API.

Comment: Have the same limitation, but from Google's documentation, it seems it will always return 100 no matter what:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list

start - The index of the first result to return. The default number of results per page is 10, so &start=11 would start at the top of the second page of results. *Note: The JSON API will never return more than 100 results, even if more than 100 documents match the query, so setting the sum of start + num to a number greater than 100 will produce an error.* Also note that the maximum value for num is 10.

Comment: That's something different--the original question was about the number of queries allowed per day, rather than the number of search results for a single query.